# Updating ArrayList Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist

I think I bit off a little more than I can chew. I'm creating a dummy music player and I wanted to add a button that a user can add a Song() object to the ArrayList. The problem is I add the Song objects to the Array in the onCreate() method. I have a button that inflates a PopUpView and in that view I have another button that takes the getText() from the Edit Fields and adds an item to the ArrayList, when the 'done' button is tapped the PopUPView is dismissed and the new Song() appears in the song list, but when I go back to the main menu and then go back to the song list the new Object that the user adds is no longer there.

```
public class AllSongsActivity<name> extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<Song>();

private AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;
private AlertDialog dialog;
private EditText songNameEditText;
private EditText artistNameEditText;
private EditText genreNameEditText;
private CheckBox isFavoriteCheckBox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_songs);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    //Create List Of Song
    songs.add(new Song("Fever", "Dua Lipa", "POP", true));
    songs.add(new Song("Lonely", "Justin Bieber", "POP", false));
    songs.add(new Song("Courage To Change", "Sia", "POP", true));
    songs.add(new Song("Monster", "Shawn Mendes", "POP", false));
    songs.add(new Song("Dance Monkey", "Tones And I", "POP", true));
    songs.add(new Song("Masterpeice", "DaBaby", "RAP", false));
    songs.add(new Song("Wolves", "Big Sean", "RAP", false));
    songs.add(new Song("Trust", "Fivo Foreign", "RAP", false));
    songs.add(new Song("Back", "Jeezy", "RAP", false));
    songs.add(new Song("Bad Boy", "Juice Wrld", "RAP", true));
    songs.add(new Song("Deeper", "DubVision", "EDM", true));
    songs.add(new Song("Sick Of You", "Jerome", "EDM", true));
    songs.add(new Song("Paul Is Dead", "Scooter", "EDM", true));
    songs.add(new Song("All I Need", "Slushii", "EDM", true));
    songs.add(new Song("Willow", "Taylor Swift", "POP", false));

    ListAdapter songAdapter = new SongAdapter(this, songs);
    listView.setAdapter(songAdapter);

    Button addSongButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_song_button);
    addSongButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popUpWindow();
        }
    });
}


public void popUpWindow() {
    dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final View addNewSongView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_song_popup_window, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(addNewSongView);
    dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    int sizeOfArray = songs.size();
    System.out.println("This is the size of the array before songs added" + sizeOfArray);
    dialog.show();

    Button addNewSongButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.done_button);
    addNewSongButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            songNameEditText = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.song_name_edit_text);
            artistNameEditText = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.arist_name_edit_text);
            genreNameEditText = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.genre_edit_text);
            isFavoriteCheckBox = (CheckBox)dialog.findViewById(R.id.favorite_checkbox);
            int songsSize = songs.size();

            String songName = songNameEditText.getText().toString();
            String artistName = artistNameEditText.getText().toString();
            String genreName = genreNameEditText.getText().toString();
            Boolean isFavorite = isFavoriteCheckBox.isSelected();

            if (songName.matches("") || artistName.matches("") || genreName.matches("")) {
                Toast.makeText(AllSongsActivity.this, "Please Fillout All Fields",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                    Song newObject = new Song(songName, artistName, genreName, isFavorite);
                    songs.add(newObject);
                    dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I've been learning Android Development for a couple of months so I know my code is really messy and not using the best techniques.

Comment: Maybe, you're creating a new instance of `AllSongsActivity` every time you're entering from main menu, then `songs` list is initialized as empty `ArrayList` and `onCreate()` is called meaning you'll have only the songs you add in `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Is there a better place to initialize the ArrayList? I feel like there should be a way to initialize it as a global variable and just reference it, like I said I'm new to Android Dev but I feel like this would be very easy to do for an IOS app using Swift.

Comment: No, I think you need to initialize variable of object `AllSongsActivity` and hold the reference to it, as it will let you to store changes. Do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code: the **songs** list is a property of AllSongsActivity. If you close AllSongsActivity - all data from the activity and the **songs** list will simply disappear!

The simple, but not correct way to save a new song use **static** modifier for the **songs**:
`static ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<String>() {{ add(new Song("Fever", "Dua Lipa", "POP", true)); add(new Song("Lonely", "Justin Bieber", "POP", false)); }};`

The correct way - learn how to store data in a database: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: Okay, so I moved the ArrayList out of the onCreate() and initialized how you suggested the app would crash when the activity opened. I did a couple more searches and stumbled upon a StackOverflow post saying to move the initialization into a static block. It works great now!! Thank you so much for pointing me to the right direction!